# Videojs не показывает видео с большим весом

Tags: php, html5, yii, видео

Добрый день:)

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему [videojs](http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/) не показывает видео с большим весом на странице сайта?

Есть 2 видео, которые весят до 120 МБ, а другие 2 видео от 500 до 900 МБ (почти до 1 гига).

Каждое видео открывается в отдельной странице. Которые маленькие по весу, их показывает при воспроизведении, а которые большие видео - изображения нет, а звук есть и они не открываются автоматически во весь экран, маленькие открываются.

В чём может быть проблема? Может где-то в настройках есть ограничение по весу?

Код встроен в фреймворк yii.

```
<video
    id="my-player"
    class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    data-setup='{}'
>
       <source src="<?= $model->video_path ?>" type="video/mp4"/>
       <p class="vjs-no-js">
           To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
           <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
              supports HTML5 video
           </a>
       </p>
</video>
```

Comment: Сравните кодеки ваших видео файлов, может в больших файлах используется другой кодек для видео потока.

Comment: @Visman А, как можно сравнить кодеки? Через программу какую?

Comment: Думаю через MediaInfo, которая в комплекте с K-Lite Codec Pack идет, можно посмотреть.

Comment: @Visman Действительно, кодек для маленьких видео - `H.264`, а для больших -
 `MPEG-4 Video`. Что делать? Я не думал, что `videojs` так будет реагировать на это, формат то по сути у видео всех один и тот же MPEG-4.

Comment: Вот нашел от разработчика самого - MP4 в браузерах обычно поддерживает только видео h264 и MP3 или аудио AAC

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, через какую программу можно переделать кодек без потери качества?

Comment: @Visman Я хочу конвертировать через Video Convert Master в формат `PC MP-4 - Standart Quality (H.264, 24 fps, Original; MPEG4 AAC LC)`, подойдет? Или сожмет качество?

Comment: Видео не занимаюсь, так что вам самому придется подобрать подходящее решение.

Comment: @Visman Буду пробовать, благодарю Вас за помощь) Вы мастер!:)